# Constructors in c++ making an object with [] instead of brackets

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Is there any way that i could **implement** a constructor  that accepts braces instead of brackets?
ex

```
class MyString
{
    char *x;
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    MyString instance[10];
    return 0;
}
```

btw i understand the idea of parentheses and we cant declare a method like so.
but i was just wondering if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing when you define an array is that you create multiple instance of the class.

For example your definition

```
MyString instance[10];
```

defines ten distinct `MyString` objects. I.e. the constructor will be called ten times, once for each object.

If your purpose is to create a single `MyString` object, and pass the value `10` to it, then you have to use either parentheses or curly-braces. And of course implement an appropriate constructor taking the value as argument.

And no there's nothing you can do to change it, it's part of the base language syntax.

Answer (score 2):

No. Constructors can only be invoked using `()` or `{}`. You *could* create a factory function taking one argument by overloading `operator[]`, but this would be an abuse of a feature that goes against best practices and would violate user expectations.

This is an example of what I mean (and would not recommend):

```
struct foo {
    int value = {};
};

struct foo_factory {
    foo operator[](int v) const {
        return foo{v};
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f = foo_factory()[42];
}
```

Comment: I thought i about overloading the [ ] operator the second the above guy answered my question. Thanks for not letting me do so!

Comment: Make a static instance of the factory class (instead of having it in the actual class) to make it look better.

Comment: @Arof: Re "the above guy"; you generally don't know in what order Stack Overflow will display answers. An answer appearing "above" for you today may appear below for you or someone else tomorrow.

Comment: @lorro Thanks. Suggestion implemented.

Comment: @JosephThomson: what I meant, instead of `struct foo_factory { ... };`, I'd do `static const struct { ... } foo_factory;`, in which case in `main()` you just have `foo f = foo_factory[42];`.